# Nearest Prototype Matlab implementation using a database

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am new to matlab an what i want to do is this:  I have a database http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/ and i want to be able to implement the NP, Nearest Prototype algorithm in matlab. Is there anyone that can give me a peace of advice or some link to a NP example usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code, I assume this dataset's first column is the label the rest are its features

```html
data = load('wine.data');

% split the dataset to training and testing
data = data(randperm(end), :);
train = data(1:floor(0.7*size(data, 1)), :);
test = data(floor(0.7*size(data, 1))+1:end, :);



% training phase
% --------------------------------------------------------
% initialize the centroid, the first column is the label

centroid = [unique(data(:, 1)) zeros(size(unique(data(:, 1)), 1), size(data, 2)-1)];


for label = unique(train(:, 1))'
    % collect all the data of under the label
    train(train(:, 1) == label, 2:end)
    % compute the centroid for the label
    centroid(centroid(:, 1) == label, 2:end) = mean(train(train(:, 1) == label, 2:end));

end

% testing phase
% --------------------------------------------------------
% initialize the prediction result
pre_result = zeros(size(test, 1), 1);
for i = 1:size(test, 1)
    dist = pdist2(test(i, 2:end), centroid(:, 2:end));
    [~, templabel] = min(dist);
    pre_result(i) = centroid(templabel, 1);

end
```

Comment: there are 3 classes, 1,2 and 3. 178 total instances. I want to be able to choose a single test vector and calculate the euclidian distance (  example: sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)  ) between the mean vector from each class and this test vector. Then i aught to compare each calculated distance and choose de smallest. The smallest distance will point to the class where our test vector belongs. Can you help me with this, Yang?

Comment: @StefanOlaru - Use Yang's code and simply use `templabel`, rather than using `centroid`.  Look at the very last `for` loop at the end of his code.

Comment: rather than using it where? can you be more code specific?

Comment: Actually, never mind.  This code will work as is.  `pre_result` will give you the actual labels.  You should probably read his code before making more comments.

Comment: Thanks for answering @rayryeng ! My problem is not that i don't want to use a centroid but rather, i want to calculate each euclidian distance between the test vector and first mean vector of first class then the second and so on. the smallest value distance needs to point to the class where the test vector belongs. Can you help me, please? I am online for further questions.

Comment: @StefanOlaru - You're **not** using the centroid.  If you look at the code, the **label** is in the first column of the result, which is what is being indexed.  `pre_result` will **already contain the labels**.  To be much more simpler,  `label == class`.  The comments in the training phase portion of the code makes this statement quite clearly.  Again, please read the code, and probably try running it and see the results.